# sql query to select all records and displaying records together which have same name in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, filter

Selecting all records but while displaying filter records when the name is same. I want to see all the records occurring once and more than once together and rest default.

I tried -

select * from sale
group by party_name

it not combined data where the name is same and it filtered in ascending order.
THE TABLE IS -

```
|1 | 2020-05-01 | Ram
|2 | 2020-05-04 | shayam
|3 | 2020-05-03 | Ram
|4 | 2020-05-15 | Mohan
|5 | 2020-05-17 | Shyam
```

THE OUTPUT I NEED

```
1 2020-05-01 Ram
3 2020-05-03 Ram
2 2020-05-04 shayam
5 2020-05-17 Shayam
4 2020-05-15 Mohan
6 2020-06-01 Ram
8 2020-06-17 Ram
7 2020-06-15 Mohan
```

Comment: Where do the new records come from?  They do not appear to be in your original table.

Comment: No i just typed it because i don't no how to filter the above record.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but this query is malformed:

```
select *
from sale
group by party_name;
```

You have an aggregation query, but are selecting columns that are not aggregated (assuming the table has more than one column).  In almost every database in existence, this returns an error.  Sadly some databases -- such as old versions of MySQL -- allow this.

It would explain, though, why you are getting one row per `party_name`.  However, the proper behavior would be an error, which happily almost all databases will provide.

Comment: Yup i am using a old version MySQL 5.1, so how to do this.

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY`.